# Swift 3 enum in functions causes app to crash

Tags: swift, enums, swift3

I'm trying to play a sound based on file name. I created an enum with all file names. Everything works, except this case, where I check for the soundType.click

```
func playSound(type: soundType) {
    var soundUrl = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: type.rawValue, ofType: "aiff")!)
    if type.rawValue == soundType.click.rawValue {
        soundUrl = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: type.rawValue, ofType: "wav")!)
    }
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundUrl)
        audioPlayer.play()
    } catch _ { }
}
```

And here is my enum

```
enum soundType: String {
    case selectAnswer = "answerSelected"
    case correctAnswer = "correctAnswer"
    case wrongAnswer = "wrongAnswer"
    case click = "click"
}
```

The problem is here where I check for "type.rawValue == soundType.click.rawValue"

Here is the error

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: Well, the program found nil, unexpectedly, while it was ... unwrapping an `Optional` value :P It's exactly what it says on the tin

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at this line of code first.

```
 var soundUrl = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: type.rawValue, ofType: "aiff")!)
 soundUrl = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: type.rawValue, ofType: "wav")!)
```

Here, **you are force unwrapping** a failable initializer. You should check if `Bundle.main.path(forResource: type.rawValue, ofType: "aiff")!)` exists first by doing something like this...

```
    if let soundUrl = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: type.rawValue, ofType: "aiff")){
        if type.rawValue == soundType.click.rawValue {
             ...
    }
```

or you could also use a guard statement..

Check this blog post by Natashtherobot to learn more about how to unwrap stuff well. https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-guard-better-than-if/

Comment: before call URL.init please check `Bundle.main.path(forResource: type.rawValue, ofType: "aiff")` too this should be nil

Comment: Bundle has a method called URLForResource, going all the way around makes no sense